# Live reload Node.js dev environment with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to work on a dev environment with Node.js and Docker.

I want to be able to:

- run my docker container when I boot my computer once and for all;
- make changes in my local source code and see the changes without interacting with the docker container (with a mount).

I've tried the [Node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) and, if I understand correctly, it is not what I'm looking for.

I know how to make the mount point, but I'm missing how the server is supposed to detect the changes and "relaunch" itself.

I'm new to Node.js so if there is a better way to do things, feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> run my docker container when I boot my computer once and for all;

[start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/) with the docker daemon or with your process manager

> make changes in my local source code and see the changes without
>   interacting with the docker container (with a mount).

You need to mount your dev app folder as a volume

```
$ docker run --name myapp -v /app/src:/app image/app
```

and set in your Dockerfile nodeJs

CMD ["nodemon", "-L", "/app"]